# Issues setting up a Magento observer module

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.6, observers

I am currently trying to add an observer on a Magento Community 1.6.2.0

I am trying to add an observer to **checkout_onepage_controller_success_action** that checks the ordered products' SKU and performs additional code that creates and emails a Voucher code if the SKU is correct.

I can create and email the codes correctly when testing on another page, but every attempt to set the method as an observer have failed with no explanation.

**in app/etc/modules/giftCheck_sales.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <giftCheck_sales>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </giftCheck_sales>
    </modules>
</config>
```

**in app/code/local/giftCheck/sales/etc**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <frontend>
        <events>
            <checkout_onepage_controller_success_action>
                <observers>
                    <giftCheck_sales>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>giftCheck_sales/observer</class>
                        <method>exportOrder</method>
                    </giftCheck_sales>
                </observers>
            </checkout_onepage_controller_success_action>
        </events>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

**in app/code/local/giftCheck/sales/models/observer.php**

```
class giftCheck_sales_Model_Observer
{
    public function exportOrder(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        die('test');
    }
}
```

My issue is no matter what I do, I can never get these observers to work. Regardless of what code I place in my observer it never gets executed.

What is the issue with (I presume my XML) the way I am setting up this observer?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To view all active modules, go to `System->Configuration->Advanced->Advanced`. If a module doesn't appear in that list, then Magento doesn't know your module exists.

As far as your code, I haven't worked with Magento 1.6.2.0 specifically, but I can see some things that might be causing you trouble. First among them is your namespace and module name. These should always begin with an uppercase letter:

```
app/etc/modules/Giftcheck_Sales.xml
app/code/local/Giftcheck/Sales/
```

Which means of course that `Giftcheck_Sales.xml` should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Giftcheck_Sales>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Giftcheck_Sales>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Another problem I see is you haven't told Magento where to find your models. There are also some problems with casing.

Your config should look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <global>
        <models>
            <giftcheck_sales>
                <class>Giftcheck_Sales_Model</class>
            </giftcheck_sales>
        </models>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <events>
            <checkout_onepage_controller_success_action>
                <observers>
                    <giftcheck_sales>
                        <class>giftcheck_sales/observer</class>
                        <method>exportOrder</method>
                    </giftcheck_sales>
                </observers>
            </checkout_onepage_controller_success_action>
        </events>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

There also seems to be a problem with your directory structure.

```
app/code/local/giftCheck/sales/models/observer.php
```

should be:

```
app/code/local/Giftcheck/Sales/Model/Observer.php
```

And the contents of that file should look something like:

```
class Giftcheck_Sales_Model_Observer
{
    public function exportOrder(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        die('test');
    }
}
```

Don't forget to correct the casing of your observer's class name.

Hope this helps.

Comment: After looking in the system log an following your advice - the issue was that although my namespace was GiftCheck it was including a file from 'Giftcheck'. After that was sorted out it worked brilliantly.

Answer (score 0):

Here some correction i can give you to add your config.xml
may be due to case sensitive issue you are not able to call your observer

**in app/code/local/giftCheck/sales/etc**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <frontend>
        <events>
            <checkout_onepage_controller_success_action>
                <observers>
                    <giftcheck_sales>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>giftcheck_sales/observer</class>
                        <method>exportOrder</method>
                    </giftcheck_sales>
                </observers>
            </checkout_onepage_controller_success_action>
        </events>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

hope this will sure work for you.

Comment: Unfortunately not. Is there a way I can check which observers are currently set up in a Magento Install? Or at least see all registered modules?

Answer (score 0):

you configuration is wrong. your code should be like this,

```
<config>
    <frontend>
    <global>
        <events>   
            <checkout_onepage_controller_success_action>
                  <observers>
                     <GiftCheck_Sales>
                <type>singleton</type>
                            <class>GiftCheck_Sales_Model_Observer</class>
                            <method>exportOrder</method>
                      </GiftCheck_Sales>
                  </observers>
             </checkout_onepage_controller_success_action>
        </events>
       </global>
  </frontend>
</config>
```

You missed global tag.And your observer class should be like this,

```
class GiftCheck_Sales_Model_Observer
{
    public function exportOrder(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
       echo "test";
    }
}
```

Thats it..!!let me know if any problem to use this code..!!

Comment: I have tried all the combinations of capitalization, adding global as you suggested, and tried all variations of sales/giftCheck_sales/GiftCheck_Sales. I then did as you suggested here and used the class name instead of sales/observer (or giftCheck_sales/observer) and still nothing!

Magento really annoys me :)

Comment: Hi.. Your model directory should be "Model" . Not "models" and observer.php file should be Observer.php ( 'O'->caps)..Check this..